# Phase rotation compensation in AOA

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, phase, signal-detection, kalman-filters

We are using $4 \times 4$ corehw antenna array with [nrf52833](https://www.nordicsemi.com/products/nrf52833) mcu as the receiver and nrf52833 as transmitter. When working on AOA Direction Finding, we found that each element in the antenna array has a some degree rotation during its design.

Therefore to compensate this phase rotation, is there any document related to it or do you have any idea about phase compensation applied to IQ samples?

Ideally, the phase difference during reference period for an antenna array is 90 degree, and other than reference samples the phase difference or rotation should be 360 degree. But when taking phase difference in my non-reference samples I am not able to get 360 degree.Therefore do you have any idea about how de-rotation or phase rotation compensation has to be done wrt to antenna rotation based on its design.